# Excel: Custom Number Format

Tags: excel

A number **123456789.1** with a cell format:

- **#,##0.00** is shown as 123,456,789.10
- **#.##0,00** is not shown as 123.456.789,10

How to achieve number shown as **123.456.789,10**?

Comment: [Here](http://www.officetooltips.com/excel/tips/change_the_decimal_point_to_a_comma_or_vice_versa.html)'s what you need.

Comment: Actually, I generate this file and I need that numbers are shown like 123.456.789,10 and not like system settings. This is a reason to use a mask format.

Answer (score 1):

If formula is an option consider using:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FIXED(A1,2,FALSE),".","$"),",","."),"$",",")
```

Comment: Beat me by six seconds! That's what I found too.

Comment: I was just watching the time difference as well :)

Comment: @Boris This may help. The easiest solution for me is set the format mask, but I'm afraid that it is impossible.

Comment: @Petra Always glad to help :)